# Relationship between attribute of vector data and raster variable in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, regression

I have a vector data of individual elements (buildings) with attributes (value, etc), and several raster grids with continuous variables. I would like to understand whether there is a relationship between the attributes of a building and the other variables - my understanding is that this would require  spatial multivariate regression.

This is a new topic for me.

Would anyone be able to advise where to begin such an analysis in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

The Online Help is usually the best place to start (when you have specified that you are using ArcGIS) and a search of [**resources.arcgis.com**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/home/) for "multivariate regression" turned up **[this document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000pr000000)**.

Comment: +1 Good advice--but the document you reference is about *classification* rather than regression. For statistical analysis of GIS data, one is generally better off starting elsewhere for guidance, because vendor GIS help pages tend to focus on the data processing and (of course) include only the methods they have implemented in the software, which are necessarily limited. (The [Idrisi docs](http://clarklabs.org/) are a notable exception.)  Textbooks, statistical packages like `R`, and even the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) are good starting places.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and sorry for taking a few days to reply